# Supply App.config file via NuGet

Tags: c#, nuget, app-config

I have some information in my nupkg that I would like to include in the consumer's application. What is the best way to include a partial app.config directly when consuming the nupkg?

I have currently done this:

- mypackage.nupkg

  - content

    - App.config

But this makes that it wants to override a user's own App.config, while there could be valuable information in there.

So I want to combine my App.config with the user's App.config.

I already saw something like this: [C#: manage Multiple App.config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018625/c-manage-multiple-app-config-files), but I cannot see how I could force the user to include my piece into its App.config.

Contents of my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="somefolder;someotherfolder;" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

How can I force the consumer to add my App.config to its own app.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do this [using .transform files](https://docs.nuget.org/create/transforming-configuration-files-using-dottransform-files):

> In NuGet's traditional way of configuration-file transformation, you
>   add a file to your package's content and give it the same name as the
>   file you want to transform, followed by a .transform extension. For
>   example, to transform a web.config file, you create a
>   web.config.transform file. **The transformation file contains XML that
>   looks like a web.config or app.config file, but it includes only the
>   sections that need to be merged into the project's configuration file**.